# Heterogeneous Robot Communication Over ROS Framework

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need to have communication between two different robots using ros framework
I have read the turtlesim tutorials but dont now what to do next.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45777/heterogeneous-robot-communication-over-ros-framework/) by [abc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3375/abc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-03**:
Please dont delete older questions by overwriting them. Nobody would be able to interpret the answers, without the appropriate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since this is a very generic question, the answer has to be very generic, too.  You should work your way through the [other tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) at [ros.org](http://ros.org).  They describe the mechanisms of ROS in detail.  One of the examples is very close to the use case you gave in a comment to your question.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a very open ended question which can't be easily answered.  In general you need to identify what data you want to communicate.  Pick existing messages or make new messages to convey that data.  And then pick topics to send the data over the ROS communication protocols.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4